# How do I import specific or old commit from bitbucket using eGit in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I have created a one branch (say submaster) from master in bitbucket and done around 4 commit from eclipse using Egit.

Now I want to import project from 2nd commit of submaster. Is it possible to import directly into eclipse or I have to first download the old commit and import into eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cherry-pick, CLI much easier, but if you must use egit, plenty of documentation, such as https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cherry_Picking